# The upper bound of an integral involving exponential function

Tags: definite-integrals, boundary-value-problem

Thanks for your attention, I need to obtain the upper bound of the following integral,
$$I = \int_0^\infty  {{e^{ - {{\left( {\ln x + a} \right)}^2}}}}  \cdot {e^{ - {{\left( {\ln \left( {x + b} \right) + c} \right)}^2}}}d\left( {\ln x} \right)$$
where $a$, $b$, $c$ are constant and $a$<0, $b \geqslant 0$.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well the $\log(x+b)$ makes it not so easy...

Comment: Yes, that is true

Comment: Maybe you can give us some hints of the context of the problem. Do you have any additional information that could help?

Comment: Thanks a lot, in fact, I want to obtain the bound(upper bound or lower bound) of the following integral, 
$$\int_0^\infty  {{e^{ - {k_1}{{\left( {\ln x - a} \right)}^2}}}}  \cdot Q\left( {{k_2}\ln \left( {x + b} \right) - c} \right)d\left( {\ln x} \right)$$
Where $k_1$, $k_2$, $a$ >0, $b \geqslant $0.
As $Q\left( x \right) = \frac{1}{2}erfc\left( {\frac{x}{{\sqrt 2 }}} \right) \leqslant \frac{1}{2}{e^{ - \frac{{{x^2}}}{2}}}$, so I want to find the upper bound of the previous integral.

Comment: Another quick comment. You have, as integration variable, $\ln x$, and your extremes are $0$ and $\infty$. That means you are integrating between $\ln x = 0$ and $\ln x \rightarrow \infty$ right?

Comment: no, 0 and $\infty $ are for $x$, not $\ln x$

Answer (score 0):

It is not a general solution, but it may point toward one. We can start considering $b=0$. Then you have 
$$
I = \int_0^\infty {{e^{ - {{\left( {\ln x + a} \right)}^2}}}} \cdot {e^{ - {{\left( {\ln {x }  + c} \right)}^2}}}d\left( {\ln x} \right)
$$
And you can make the substitution $y=\ln x$ therefore changing the limit of the integral to $-\infty$ and $+\infty$ getting you the integral to study
$$
I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty {{e^{ - {{\left( {y + a} \right)}^2}}}} \cdot {e^{ - {{\left( {y  + c} \right)}^2}}}d {y} $$
that should be easy to study. I will expand this answer as soon as I have done more, but maybe it will help the OP in some way (I hope). 
If posting such an answer is considered bad form (because it not really an answer) just drop a comment below and I will delete it.

And to approach this problem you can find a nice work here: http://www.tina-vision.net/docs/memos/2003-003.pdf

**EDIT:** an additional information that could help you is that we dealing here with a convolution of functions, something that has quite a solid theory behind it... You may want to look into it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this is not what i want. This result only considered the case $b$=0. i prefer a more generalanswer, but thanks anyway.